# Qt - Set the output path of .o file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Here's the structure of the folder:

```
TEST
|-- DIR1
|   |-- TEST1.cpp
|   `-- TEST1.h
|-- DIR2
|   |-- TEST2.cpp
|   `-- TEST2.h
`-- main.cpp
```

After `qmake -project`, `qmake TEST.pro`, `make`, I got:

```
TEST
|-- DIR1
|   |-- TEST1.cpp
|   `-- TEST1.h
|-- DIR2
|   |-- TEST2.cpp
|   `-- TEST2.h
|-- Makefile
|-- TEST
|-- TEST.pro 
|-- TEST1.o
|-- TEST2.o
|-- main.cpp
`-- main.o
```

I want to specify the output path of the `.o` file generated from `.cpp` file and put `.o` file in the same folder of its `.cpp` file, like:

```
TEST
|-- DIR1
|   |-- TEST1.cpp
|   |-- TEST1.o
|   `-- TEST1.h
|-- DIR2
|   |-- TEST2.cpp
|   |-- TEST2.o
|   `-- TEST2.h
|-- Makefile
|-- TEST
|-- TEST.pro
|-- main.cpp
`-- main.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qmake` puts all object files in one directory and you cant change it. But you can add this line to your `.pro` file

```
OBJECTS_DIR = .obj
```

Then it will create a directory named obj and put all object files there.